# store cart in tables and sessions

Tags: php, laravel, session

I'm making API and I have a `carts` table that contains

```
 id
 product_id
 user_id
 quantity
```

How could I create a cart without a user ?
How could I do it using sessions?

My Controller

```
    $cart = Cart::updateOrCreate(
        ['product_id' => Request()->product_id, 'user_id' => Request()->user_id],
        ['quantity' => Request()->quantity]
    );
```

Comment: is it card or cart?

Comment: @Saly3301 Sorry My bad it's carts

Comment: Are you using the api routes file in Laravel?